# Partition function of Hydrogen atoms problem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, atomic-physics, singularities, partition-function, regularization

I know there are several questions asking this problem, but I found this problem has not been solved yet to me. I will repeat the problem and state my view.

---

Consider the statistical mechanics of a system of Hydrogen atoms. By the spirit of Gibbs ensemble theory, one have to calculate the partition function

$$
Z = tre^{-\beta H}
$$

But as we know the spectrum of Hydrogen atom has infinite bound states with negative energy. So the partition function $Z$ is divergent:

$$
Z > \sum_{bound-states} e^{-\beta E_n} >\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1
$$

And all the thermodynamics quantities are divergent as well. Degeneracy and scattering states make things worse.

---

To me, introducing an IR regulator by putting atoms in a finite box or considering the plasma state at high temperature do not solve this problem.

By the standard derivation in textbooks, the Gibbs ensemble theory permits Hamiltonians with any kinds of spectrum. The example of Hydrogen is an example showing there exists a Hamiltonian with infinite negative energy levels. "r" in the Hamiltonian should be considered a parameter, so physically we should not introduced a box to be an IR regulator.

I guess the problem indicates that the Gibbs ensemble theory does not permits long range interactions. Maybe such a system does not have an extensive energy, so we should have a different formal definition of entropy?

Comment: You seem to have discovered a genuinely interesting theoretical headache. The Hydrogen atom has degeneracy of $2n^2$ for energy level $n$, so the bound state sum is like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n^2e^{+\beta R/n^2}$; yes, if you go by this, the $2n^2$ will eventually cause a singularity. However, plugging in room temperature, the ground state contributes a term so huge in importance that it is equivalent to $n\approx e^{270}$, so much so my calculator doesn't compute it. In reality, it is grand canonical ensemble that is trustworthy, i.e. some chemical potential should save us from the singularity.